# How to tell JAXB not to generate @XmlSchemaType Annotation

Tags: soap, jaxb

following xsd (partial):

```
<xs:complexType name="Fruit">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="type" type="FruitType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="FruitType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="ABC">
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="DEF">
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="GHI">
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="JKL">
        </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Generating code with xjc will generate the following java code (FruitType is an Enum):

```
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    protected FruitType fruit;
```

When generating a SOAP WebService with JAX-WS the following element will be generated:

```
<xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
```

Which ist obviously wrong. I'd expect this to be

```
<xs:element name="type" type="FruitType"/>
```

If I delete this line by hand

```
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
```

in my Java Code everything in the wsdl is fine :

```
<xs:element name="type" type="tns:FruitType"/>
```

So the question is: How can I tell JAXB not to generate the @XmlSchemaType?

Comment: Please write your solution as answer, it's hardly noticeable inside the question.

Comment: @dbaer You solution works for me. Please turn this to an answer and you will get upvotes.

Comment: The answer gives a nice workaround, but actually this is a [bug](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/986) in Jaxb; see also [CXF-6747](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6747).

Answer (score 7):

Instead of referencing FruitType with type

```
<xs:complexType name="Fruit">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="type" type="FruitType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

the trick ist to have a simpleType inline:

```
    <xs:complexType name="Fruit">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="type">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="FruitType"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

this will generate the correct java file and WSDL:

```
<xs:element name="type" type="tns:FruitType"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @dbaer. Is this a solution or workaround ?