# Enum type erased to string in SOAP WSDL after deployed on JBoss

Tags: soap, jboss, wsdl, cxf

Here is a SOAP web service. It was initially defined via wsdl/xsd. Then Java classes was generated by Apache CXF. Then a war was built and deployed onto JBoss.

**The problem.** The wsdl JBoss exposes into the world significantly differs from the one written by me - in the example below custom enum type `Fruit` was erased into raw string type. As result, there is no type check about the enum - any non empty string value could be "successfully" passed by a client to the service without a schema-not-satisfied error; Java service implementation receives `null` enum in such cases (although it's a mandatory param).

**The question.** How prevent such enum type erasure in runtime? Or. How to teach the web service to check requests strictly about enums?

The original definition of the service:

```
<!-- SOAP WSDL: -->

<wsdl:operation name="pickFruit">
 <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.com/ws/pickFruit"/>
 <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal"/>
 </wsdl:input>
 <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal"/>
 </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>

<!-- XSD, the request: -->

<xs:element name="pickFruitRequest" type="pickFruitRequest"/>
<xs:complexType name="pickFruitRequest">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="fruit" type="Fruit" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- XSD, the enum: -->

<xs:simpleType name="Fruit">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="orange"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="kiwi"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="potato"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The WSDL exposed by JBoss:

```
<!-- http://localhost:8080/example/PickFruitEndpoint?wsdl -->

<xs:complexType name="pickFruitRequest">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="fruit" type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**UPDATE.** Request class auto-generated by CXF:

```
public class PickFruitRequest {
  @XmlElement(required = true)
  @XmlSchemaType(name = "string") // it forces type erasure!
  protected Fruit fruit;
```

Although `<xs:restriction base="xs:string">` looks like a correct definition for an enum, it turns it leads CXF to add a `@XmlSchemaType(name = "string")` which leads JBoss to generate a "bad" wsdl in runtime.

JBoss EAP 6.4.0, Spring 4, Apache CXF, Java 7

Comment: Please, would you provide both WSDL files in full as attachments or something. Are you sure that the one you create is valid?

Comment: It's tricky to publish full files because of closed sources... But I found the root of the problem - you can see the update.

Comment: I see. I was asking because I have some doubts that type references are done properly in the wsdl. Maybe the interpreter takes string for default when it is not sure what to do. Otherwise the enum definition looks OK to me...

Comment: why you haven't mention how to solve this problem...

Comment: This question led me to finding the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381873/813852